# When $x\rightarrow{0}, x^{8k}(1+x^2)\approx x^{8k}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Why, when $x\rightarrow{0}, x^{8k}(1+x^2)\approx x^{8k}$?
I think It should be $x^{8k}(1+x^2)\approx 0(1+0)=0?$

Comment: Sure, but the question is about the behavior of the function as $x \to 0$, not just the single limit itself.

Comment: I think the point is that for small $x$, $1+x^2$ is virtually constant ($\approx 1$) so it does not contribute much to how the function varies. Of course, it goes to zero as $x$ goes to zero, but it tells you *how* it goes to zero.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $$x^{8k}(1+x^2)=x^{8k}+x^{8k+2}\approx x^{8k}$$

Answer (score 1):

The real notation should be $\;x^{8k}(1+x^2)\sim_x^{8k}$, in the sense of *asymptotic analysis*, two functions being *equivalent near* $0$, roughly, if their qotient tends to $1$ as $x$ tends to $0$. The notation $\approx` *not* a mathematician's notation, but a physicist's.

This relation between functions defined in a neighbourhood of $0$ has two main properties:

1. If $f(x)\to \ell\ne 0$, then $f(x)\sim_0\ell$ and conversely.
2. It is compatible with multiplication and division, i.e. if $f(x)\sim_0 f_1(x)$ and $g(x)\sim_0 g_1(x)$, then
   $$f(x)g(x)\sim_0 f_1(x)g_1(x)\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\sim_0\frac{f_1(x)}{g_1(x)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

I think you confuse the $\rightarrow$ with $\approx$; indeed as $x \to 0$, the expression will converge to 0 (provided that $k \geq 0$), but the symbol $\approx$ in this case does not express its numerical value when $x \to 0$, but moreso his behaviour.